# Inserting code into C# methods right before compilation

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, compilation, roslyn

I have a couple of methods that are being called from a WinForms app's entry point. These methods in turn call others and sometimes each other.

At the entry of each method, I have inserted code as follows:

```
public static bool IsDebug
{
    #if (DEBUG)
        return (true);
    #else
        return (false);
    #endif
}

public void SomeMethod ()
{
    if (IsDebug) { Logger.WriteMethodTrace(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name); }
}
```

There are two problems with this approach:

- It is written by hand in each method.
- It uses reflection which is too slow for frequently called methods.

.
**REFLECTION**: The new C# `nameof(parameter)` keyword works nicely for parameter names but I haven't found a similar construct for method names. I thought about creating some sort of a static dictionary to hold `Type` and `MethodInfo` details but there seems to be no way to extract the method name at runtime without reflection to use as a key in the dictionary.

**WRITTEN BY HAND**: Even if there was a solution to avoid reflection, each method would need to be altered by hand, which is tedious and error-prone. I was wondering if there is a way to insert a line of code just-in-time before compilation. Not sure is a VS extension or Roslyn would help here. Ideally, if auto-insertion is possible, the insertion should happen without actually modifying the source code.

Please note that analyzing the stack trace is not an option. I've been down that road and it is slow and unpleasant.

Any pointers/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) paradigm. Most known representative in C# world is PostSharp. Its free version can do what you want to.

Comment: Why not simply use a TraceListener and switch it on or off as needed in app.config?

Comment: @Evk: Even though the question has been answered, PostSharp seems like a good suggestion to explore. Thanks!

Comment: @RaheelKhan consider that with current approach you cannot swtich your logging level at runtime (actually you cannot switch is even via configuration) - you have to recompile your code to do that. Most often you want to enable debug-level logging on already running application.

Comment: @Evk: You're right. However, when posting a question on SO, I tend to narrow down context and code to have a concise question. The context here isn't about how to log using best practices. The accepted answer is flexible enough for my purpose (excluding automation).

Comment: Sure, accepted answer perfectly fits asked question, just made a note on a related subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# 5.0 has a nice feature for you. I think it will be usefull for you to try this:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void LogMethodNameInDebug(
    [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "", 
    [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Logger.WriteMethodTrace(memberName);
)


public void SomeMethod()
{
    LogMethodNameInDebug(); // don't fillin the methodnames yourself, the compiler will do.
}
```

---

The `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` will exclude the method when compiling it as a Release build. Look for more info: [MSDN - ConditionalAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622(v=vs.71).aspx)

And the `[CallerMemberName]` will be filled compiletime *(it fills out the parameters on the caller, so no reflection or stack analysing is used)* . More info about `[CallerMemberName]` here: [MSDN - CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Nitpick: that's a feature of C# 5.0, not .Net 4.5.

Comment: @Jeroen, Thanks! This is perfect. On top of this, I could use a Roslyn-based extension to make sure this method is called at the start of each function.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Yes, that attribute is from .Net 4.5, but that's not the important part, which is [caller information support in the compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And you can use caller information with C# 5.0 and .Net 4.0 using [a library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/) that provides the attributes. Conversely, caller information won't work with C# 4.0 and .Net 4.5, even though the attributes are available.

Comment: @svick A, `*light bulb*`  You're right. C# 5.0 is responsible for filling in the parameters. I'll correct it. Thanks for critical reading.